# ColladaLoader hollow structures cannot be read properly

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, collada

I currently have some open source `.dae` data, but I found that as long as it is in the hollow structure file format, it is cannot be read normally by `three.js` `ColladaLoader()`.

```
let loaderDae = new ColladaLoader();
loaderDae.load('assets/W_1P4GK6NH0X/W_1P4GK6NH0X.dae', (gltf: any) => {
  
  this.model = gltf.scene.children[0];   
  this.model.position.multiplyScalar(0);
  this.scene.add(this.model);
});
```

[image]

But it can preview through [blender](https://www.blender.org/):

[image]

Is there any method or tool to detect the integrity of the archive and repair it.

Example file [link](https://gitlab.com/po_developer/dae-file-example/-/tree/main)(W_1P4GK6NH0X).

Comment: The Collada spec is very complicated and hard to fully support. Can you try to convert you DAEs to glTF instead? This can be done with Blender or https://github.com/KhronosGroup/COLLADA2GLTF.

Comment: In glTF, check this [link](https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/load-models/)

Comment: @Mugen87 I have tried one of these online file transfer services. When it converts these `.dae` files to glTF , the `.dae` file contains three .jpg texture links. I found that the links were lost after the file transfer, and there was only one left.I will try the tool you recommend on github, I am not familiar with `blender` this tool.

Comment: @Mugen87 Does it have more detailed instructions, I am a mac system, I can't understand the instructions on its README.md.

Comment: If you struggle with the command line, import the DAE into Blender and export it to glTF.